# Buffer Overflow Stack Guard

Tags: buffer-overflow

I'm not sure If I'm posting in the right spot for this specific assignment. But I hope someone can help me.

It's about Buffer Overflow

http://nsfsecurity.pr.erau.edu/bom/Smasher.html

and:

http://nsfsecurity.pr.erau.edu/bom/StackGuard.html

Would you guys happen to know how I could get it to show "Oh, Bother". It's about Stack Guard and Smasher.

I tried entering "D", as it did say a hint for ACSII 0x44, but I'm lost like hell.

Comment: You should talk to your TA's / professor.

Comment: What _exactly_ are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically get that to spit out "Oh, Bother" where the "enter something" area is for the box.

Answer (score 0):

It would be too long a tutorial to make. As is described in *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective*, basically you need to overwrite the return address so that when a function returns (in assembly language, `ret`) the `%pc` counter is set to some address (often, on the stack). Then the program continues to execute on that *wrong* address so that you get to execute something else.

You need to disassemble the binary and examine the assembly. Single stepping with a `gdb` or `ntsd` might help.

Comment: I tried everything you gave, but sadly I didn't get the "oh, bother" response.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very late but I just found this. The D must go in the buffer overflow. For example, HELLOHOWARD has the D in the buffer overflow.